# Join parts of two files together in Bash

Tags: bash, opensuse, cat

I hope to draw on the knowledge of those who know far more about scripting than I.  I have two files, F1 and F2, where F2 is located in a sub-directory of F1.  I need to output a new file, F3, that has the entire contents of F1, followed by the contents of F2 **but excluding the first line of F2** (the contents obtained by doing 'tail +2 subdir/F2').  My attempts so far have been fruitless, so any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat "F1" > "F3"
tail +2 "subdir/F2" >> "F3"
```

This will write `F1` into `F3`, and then append the `tail` output. It's called [output redirection](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `cp F1 F3` for the first step?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I'm not sure what file attributes `cp` preserves by default. But you're right, `cp "F1" "F3"` would also work.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use command grouping to obtain a one-liner:

```
{ cat F1; sed 1d dir/F2; } > F3
```